# Kibana subtracting the values of 2 indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have 2 indices in kibana 4:

1st index is basing time from events (Date Created)

2nd Index is basing time from events (Date Closed)

Both are date values and I want to create a query which will return the total amount of docs Date Created (Today) - total amount of docs Date Closed (Today)

If this is not possible is it possible if i have both fields in one index?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have both the *date* values within the same index so that you can do the **subtraction** using a [scripted](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html#scripted-fields) *field* in `Kibana`. You could simply have your script as such:

```
doc.['date_created'].value - doc.['date_closed'].value
```

----------------^----------------------------------------^ Make sure to give your exact field names

And then you could use this scripted field as a **Date Historgram** to show the total count of the docs within the retrieved date range.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Benc did it work? Are you getting the desired output?

Comment: I have tried the following scripted field called test:

doc['Entities.Ticket.Date_Created.#text'].value - doc['Entities.Ticket.Date_Closed.#text'].value

however in kibana if i filter for:

Unique Count: 'Entities.Ticket.Date_Created.#text' = 43
Unique Count: 'Entities.Ticket.Date_Closed.#text' = 6
Unique Count: 'test' = 43

Is there something I am missing?

If I switch created and closed round i still get 43

Comment: **Unique Count** is the scripted field you created? And I can't understand the latter part of the above comment. If you can elaborate a bit more? How're you trying to filter in `Kibana`? and what's the expected output?

Comment: Sorry let me start from the beginning, I am trying to create a dashboard. Currently I have 2 metric visualizations:

1) Date_Created - Total docs where this = today
2) Date_Closed - Total docs where this = today

I am now trying to create a 3rd visualization metric where the output is 1 - 2.

So if:

1 = 43
2 = 6
3 = 37

Does that make sense?

Unique Count is me trying to create the widget filtering.

Comment: So doesn't the third metric show you the correct value (1-2) ? You're using the **scripted field** in order to get the count in your third metric right? Please show the exact script you're using for the scripted field!